# Python-pandasの階層型インデックスにおいて、親子関係を保ったまま親をシャッフルすることはできるのでしょうか。

Tags: python, pandas

**- 環境**
Mac
Python 3.7.3
Jupyter Notebook 5.7.8

**- やりたいこと**
親ID列・子ID列を持ったデータフレームがあります。
このとき、全行を単純にランダムソートするのではなく、同じ親IDを持つ行をグループ化した上で、そのグループをランダムソートできるでしょうか。

**- やったこと**
一部の抽出対象のparent-idが格納された配列を用意。
isinメソッドでマッチしたデータを出力しようとしましたが、parent-idをひとかたまりにランダム出力されるのではなく、単純なランダムソートで出力されてしまいます。

Python Code

```py
lis = [2, 3, 1] #parent-idが1~3までのものが出力対象
test_df = pd.DataFrame({"parent-id": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
                        "child-id": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]})

f = lambda x: x[(x["parent-id"].isin(lis))]
test_df.groupby(["parent-id"]).apply(f).sample(frac=1, random_state=0)
```

[image: 出力結果]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

結論、user10685さんに記載いただいた内容を参考にして、groupbyを意識したことにより、以下のtipsで解決いたしました。
[Shuffle a pandas dataframe by groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45585860/shuffle-a-pandas-dataframe-by-groups)

fixしたコードは以下です。

```py
lis = [2, 3, 1]
test_df = pd.DataFrame({"parent-id": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
                        "child-id": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]})
groups = [test_df for _, test_df in test_df[(test_df["parent-id"].isin(lis))].groupby('parent-id')]
random.shuffle(groups)
pd.concat(groups).reset_index(drop=True)
```

[image: 親単位でのグループシャッフル]

Answer (score 0):

`apply`した段階で`DataFrameGroupBy`オブジェクトではなく`DataFrame`になり、小グループ単位での操作はできなくなります。ですので

```py
lis = [2, 3, 1] #parent-idが1~3までのものが出力対象
test_df = pd.DataFrame({"parent-id": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
                        "child-d": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]})

f = lambda x: x[(x["parent-id"].isin(lis))].sample(frac=1, random_state=0)
test_df.groupby(["parent-id"]).apply(f)
```

のようにするとよいかと。

ref:
- [pd.DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)
- [pd.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます。ご提示いただいたアプローチで試行したのですが、グループ内のchild-idはシャッフルされるもparent-idはシャッフルされず、、でした。

Comment: @yoshi 自己回答を見るに、私は誤読に基づいて回答してしまったようですね。この場合、この回答は承認されている*べきではありません*。

Comment: 誤解を誘発させる質問の記載方法であり、失礼いたしました。今後は期待する出力結果も合わせて掲載するようにします。